# angular2 AOT build failed, can't resolve module @angular/core/src/di/opaque_token from undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

I am using

```
 "@angular/common": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.3.0",
 "typescript": "2.0.3",
 "webpack": "1.13.0",
```

When i am running

```
node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json
```

I got this error:

can't resolve module @angular/core/src/di/opaque_token from undefined

Can you run ngc to do AOT in your system?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Are you using `yarn` ? 2) Have you try recently to upgrade to angular v4 ? Please try to remove `node_modules` and just run `npm i`. Let me know if it works after that.

Comment: no yarn, why using that? Also from angular.io, the latest version is 2.4, I don't see any v4 information

Comment: upgraded to angular 2.4.0, same error. If you can run aot, can you share your details?

Comment: my error, once I put all latest version, it worked, thanks